# How to run a copy of flutter project without overwriting the existing app?

Tags: android, flutter

So I've created a flutter project and want to reuse the code. Instead of rewriting the code, i copied the project and edit the code. When i run the project, it overwrites my previous application that has been installed on my phone. How can i run the project and not overwrite my previous application? Are there any files that i have to rewrite? All answer will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For android, you can change **applicationId** in build.gradle file.

For iOS, you can change **bundle identifier** in Xcode.